# JPanel not working with setSize & setPrefferedSize

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Please explain why it does not work, also could you post a solution to solve this issue. Thank you very mucho in advance.

```
public class Run extends JFrame{

    /** Fields **/
    static JPanel jpanel;
    private int x, y;

    /** Constructor **/
    public Run() {
        /** Create & Initialise Things **/
        jpanel = new JPanel();
        x = 400; y = 400;

        /** JPanel Properties **/
        jpanel.setBackground(Color.red);
        jpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 30));


        /** Add things to JFrame and JPanel **/
        add(jpanel);

        /** JFrame Properties **/
        setTitle("Snake Game");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setCursor(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(new Dimension(x,y));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /** Set the Cursor **/
    public void setCursor() {
        setCursor (Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    }

    /** Main Method **/
    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
        Run run = new Run();
        run.setCursor();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *it does not work*?

Comment: Well I have the JFrame of size 400, 400 but when I try to set the JPanel to size 30, 30 it will just inherit the original size from the JFrame.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is, `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout`, which will try and size the content to fit the parent container. While `BorderLayout` will try and use the preferred size as a hint, if the available space is greater or less then, it will automatically adjust to allow the center content (the default position) to fill the entire available space of the parent container.

You could try using a `FlowLayout` or `GridBagLayout` which is more likely to honour the preferred size in more situations

Take a look at [How to layout components on containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: Just remember, layouts are fun ;)

Comment: I have seen your profile looking at it you have experience with programming. I am currently on my second year of university and would like some material in Java (I started it 2 months ago), please let me know, I always like taking advice from people who actually have experience.

Greetings

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do.  A good place to start is with the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), try stuff and ask questions ;) - I'd also say that one of the greatest strengths of any developer is the ability to research a problem, seek answers to questions that have already being asked. The ability to be prepared to abandon a train of thought or development for a better solution is also important and the experience to know when to do so. An understanding of [Design Patterns](http://www.oodesign.com/) will hold you in good stead regardless of the lanuage ;)

Comment: If I have a `JMenuBar` at the top of the `JFrame`, will the `BorderLayout` account for it when sizing the `JPanel`?

Comment: The JMenuBar should be applied to the frame via the setJMenuBar call, but essentially, yes

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`pack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) method. From Java Docs:

> `public void pack():` Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents....

---

You should use this method at the end of the constructor:

```
...
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setVisible(true);
pack();
```

**Edit:**

If you want the JFrame to keep a size and a JPanel to also keep a size. You can try the following:

- Create a JPanel and add it to the JFrame. Note that this panel will be resized
- Create a second JPanel and add it to the previous JPanel, so it will keep its size.

Something like this:

```
public Run()
{
    /** Create & Initialise Things **/
    jpanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel jpanel2 = new JPanel();
    x = 400;
    y = 400;

    /** JPanel Properties **/
    jpanel2.setBackground(Color.red);
    jpanel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
    jpanel.add(jpanel2);        

    /** Add things to JFrame and JPanel **/
    add(jpanel);

    /** JFrame Properties **/
    ...
}
```

**Edit2:** You can also try [*absolute positioning*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html):

```
public Run()
{
    /** Create & Initialise Things **/
    jpanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel jpanel2 = new JPanel();
    x = 400;
    y = 400;

    jpanel.setLayout(null);

    Insets insets = jpanel2.getInsets();
    Dimension size = jpanel2.getPreferredSize();
    jpanel2.setBounds(125 + insets.left, 100 + insets.top, size.width, size.height);

    /** JPanel Properties **/
    jpanel2.setBackground(Color.red);
    jpanel.add(jpanel2);

    /** Add things to JFrame and JPanel **/
    add(jpanel);

    /** JFrame Properties **/
    ...
}
```

Comment: Herm... I tried that before but I don't want the main frame to change size to fit its sub components. Also I tried using the setPrefferedSize with pack(), and it does absolutely nothing...

Comment: @codenerd See edit and also see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316454/can-you-set-a-permanent-size-for-a-jpanel-inside-of-a-jframe).

Comment: Herm, I also tried that before, but then I dont have control where I want the jpanel2 to be, I ever tried setLocation(); but the JpANEL2 does not move from the center.

Comment: Try [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html), to locate Components in absolute positions.

Comment: No christian, muchas gracias por la ayuda, pero I used the answer bellow.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
jpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 30));
jpanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(20, 30));
jpanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(20, 30));
```

I wouldn't recommend it, but it should fix the size (as long as the frame's layout manager doesn't ignore the values). You need to learn how to use layout managers.